# In internet Explorer 9 and Hotmail, is there a way to open an HTML attachment directly?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, download-manager, attachments, hotmail

I just ran the updates on a Windows PC, and Internet Explorer 9 was installed. Now the user has lost the option to open HTML attachments in Hotmail. Other attachments provide an option to open, but HTML attachments now have the "save and open" option disabled.

Any thoughts on how I can recover this functionality, other than downgrading?

Update: I tried to open an html attachment on another computer with ie9, and there it provides an open option.

Update: It seems the reason it works on the other machine is that ie9 is not the default browser. When it is set to being the default browser, the option to open disappears. Annoying.

Still looking for a solution.

Comment: What happens when you try to open a HTML attachment

Comment: The download bar pops up at the bottom of the window up with a drop down list and a cancel button. In the drop down list are the options to "save" (default), and "save and open" (disabled/greyed out).

Comment: So you can only save the HTML attachment?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I just tried it on different machine, and ie 9 provides an open option that one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into the Active-x controls within IE, it may be blocking the file. Not sure exactly which option it is but it will be set to disabled

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the Windows Attachment Manager (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/883260):

"High Risk: If the attachment is in the list of high risk file types and is from the restricted zone, Windows blocks the user from accessing the file. If the file is from the Internet zone, Windows prompts the user before accessing the file.

Moderate Risk: If the attachment is in the list of moderate risk file types and is from the restricted or Internet zone, Windows prompts the user before accessing the file.

Low Risk: If the attachment is in the list of low risk file types, Windows will not prompt the user before accessing the file, regardless of the file’s zone information."

You may want to try adding pdf to the Moderate/Low risk file type list.

Appropriate group policy settings can be found at the following:
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Attachment Manager